# Error Domain=kAFAssistantErrorDomain Code=209 "(null)"

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, speech-recognition, sfspeechrecognizer

I am facing an issue with the `SFSpeechRecognizer`. After few seconds of starting the application I start getting the error

> Error Domain=kAFAssistantErrorDomain Code=209 "(null)"" and "Error
>   Domain=kAFAssistantErrorDomain Code=203 "Timeout"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Timeout,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x170049990 {Error Domain=SiriSpeechErrorDomain
>   Code=100 "(null)"}}

and the application stops recognization.

I am trying to `endAudio()` and then again start it every 20 seconds as Apple does not allow us to recognize for more than a minute.

Any help regarding this will really be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find any solution? We have just hit this on an iOS 11 device.

Comment: I have the same thing. It only though happens if I have QuickTime mirroring my app at the same time. I have a hunch it might direct the voice input to laptop or something similar...

Comment: maybe try on the device only as these errors are not consistent on the simulator vs a real device

Comment: I am getting exactly the same thing: Error 209, 203 and 100

Comment: I am having the same issue with `endAudio()`. But for continuous transcribing, I have tried to call it every minute, so that I wouldn't have to call `endAudio()`, and the speech recognition still works fine.

Answer (score 6):

This work for me. Try this when you want to close the recognitiontask:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
        guard let task = self.recognitionTask else {
            fatalError("Error")
        }
        task.cancel()
        task.finish()
    }
```