# SFSpeechRecognizer isn't working properly in IOS 13.2

Tags: ios, swift, speech, sfspeechrecognizer

In IOS 13.1, everything worked just fine. Since 13.2, the SFSpeechRecognizer is giving me a hard time. The speech recognition takes way longer than before and the result.IsFinal bool is never true.

I am not just struggling with these errors in my app but also getting them in the official Sample Code Project ( https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/recognizing_speech_in_live_audio ).

Is anyone else facing similar problems??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been experiencing the same problem with iOS 13.2

Apple just released iOS 13.3, and fixed the bug you are experiencing with SFSpeechRecognizer.

The same bug in macOS Catalina 10.15.1 has been fixed with the just released macOS Catalina 10.15.2

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems recently where the recognition task would not end properly. In some parts of the code I found that:

```
self.recognitionTask = nil
```

wasn't enough to end the task so I found this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56921146/9350165

However, it was throwing errors. I assumed that it's because I was using swiftUI so I just took the important parts:

```
self.recognitionTask?.cancel()
self.recognitionTask?.finish()
self.recognitionTask = nil
```

And it works... I don't know if the nil is still needed but I left it in there just in case.

Cheers~

Comment: My problem is that isFinal never becomes true. Before iOS 13.2, everything worked just fine.  But it looks like that it is an iOS problem. Others are having the same issue: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/392071#392071

Comment: in my case, when you want to stop record / play this code worked:

self.audioEngine.stop()
inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)
self.recognitionRequest = nil
 self.recognitionTask = nil